# Embeding a playa in matrix using tabs

Tags: matrix, templates, playa

I am trying to build tabs using a matrix with a playa inside of it my basic code looks something like this.

I did something like this inside before and works. does anyopne know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="nwt_3rd_order_location_group" 
   show_pages="only" show_pages="no"
   limit="1"
   disable="member_data|pagination"
   parse="inward"
   } 

<dl class="tabs contained">
     {discipline_3rd_order var_prefix="discipline_matrix"}
        {discipline_matrix:m_p_discipline var_prefix="mx_disipline_playa"}
          <dd  {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if}><a href="#simpleContained{url_title}">{mx_disipline_playa:discipline_short_name}</a></dd>
                    {/discipline_matrix:m_p_discipline}
                {discipline_3rd_order}
</dl>
<ul class="tabs-content contained">
           {discipline_3rd_order var_prefix="discipline_matrix"}
             {discipline_matrix:m_p_discipline var_prefix="mx_disipline_playa"}
        <li {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if} id="simpleContained{url_title}Tab"> 

            <div class="row">  

                                    {mx_disipline_playa:discipline_description}

                                    {discipline_matrix:m_dynamic_map_3rd_order} 

                       </div> 
                </li>

             {/discipline_matrix:m_p_discipline}
          {/discipline_3rd_order}

 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tabs and a playa inside a matrix with var=prefix](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/23973/tabs-and-a-playa-inside-a-matrix-with-var-prefix)

Comment: Is is a variation that has very different results, I tried to update the code here so it probably looks more similar then it did, but this original post rendered gibberish on the page and the new problem is stacking tabs.

Comment: Your code could really use some cleanup (indentation is crazy). That said, it looks like `{discipline_3rd_order}` is closed incorrectly near the top (should be `{/discipline_3rd_order}`). Not sure if that is a genuine bug in your code or just a copy/paste issue though.